# Psycopg2 closed connections in fact just iddle

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I use psycopg2 for manipulating data in postgresql db.

```
class Global_db_handler:
    def __init__(self, host, port, db, user, password, app_name):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.db = db
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.appname = app_name
        if not self.connect_to_db():
            raise Exception("Can't connect to the global db on initialization")
        
    def __del__(self):
        self.connection.close()
        
    def connect_to_db(self):
        try:
            self.connection.close()
        except:
            pass
        try:
            self.connection = psycopg2.connect(host = self.host, port = self.port, database = self.db,
                                           user = self.user, password = self.password, 
                                           application_name = self.appname, connect_timeout=3,
                                           tcp_user_timeout = 3000)
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return False
            
    def foo1(self):
        for tries in range(2):
            try:
                if self.connect_to_db():
                    *do things*
                    self.connection.close()
                    
                    return
            except psycopg2.OperationalError as e:
                print(e)
        raise Exception("Error in foo1")
            
    def foo2(self):
        for tries in range(2):
            try:
                if self.connect_to_db():
                    
                    *do things*
                    self.connection.commit()
                    self.connection.close()
                    return
            except psycopg2.OperationalError as e:
                print(e)
        raise Exception("Error in foo2")
```

As you can see - the connection is closed in every possible way. Each 30 minutes foo1 and foo2 are called. And each 30 minutes I see yet another iddle connection in `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;` . It is a problem because db falls when they accumulate to big number.

How can I close connection properly?

Comment: 1) This `except: pass` is not helping as you are eating any exception error messages that might indicate whether the close is actually not happening. 2) `tail` the Postgres log to see what is actually happening on the database side. 3) Are you sure the connections are all coming from this code?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver `except: pass` there is for the case if connection is already closed. I'm sure that they are coming from this code because I use unique `appname` for it.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver there are no errors in postgres log. The last message is `database system is ready to accept connections` after restart few hours ago.

Comment: 1) `except: pass` will also hide errors where the connection is not closed and you try to close it and it fails. A `pass` in the `except` clause is just a bad idea. 2) The purpose of looking at/tailing the log is to see if there are connect/disconnect pairs. In other words is the code actually doing what it is supposed to?

Comment: Since you are closing and reopening the database connection with each call to `connect_to_db()` anyway, there is no reason to keep the connection as an instance variable.  Instead, run your database operations inside of `with` context managers in each method, *e.g.* `with conn as psycopg2.connect(self.connstring), cur as conn.cursor:`